# Codeigniter Ajax request appeared twice in view and database

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I have created a comment library to handle comments all over my website developed by CI

I am adding comments using ajax so i have came up with practice to have the function located in **MY_Controller** that handle the ajax

```
public function comment_add()
    {
        echo $this->comments->add(); 
    }
```

and in **AJAX** Jquery code noting that category is one of controller names as any controller will havethe access to comment_add() found in parent controller

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    dataString=$("#myform").serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: base_url+"snc/category/comment_add",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data){
        $(data).hide().insertAfter('#inserAfterThis').slideDown('slow');
        $('#comment_new').val('');
        }
    }
  );
});
```

and in my **Comments library**

```
public function add()
    { 
        $post_id=$this->get_post_id();
        $post_type=$this->get_post_type();

        if(!$post_id || !$post_type || !$this->user_id)
            return false;

        $id=$this->ci->comments_model->comment_add($this->user_id,$post_id,$post_type);
        if($id)
        {
            return $this->_markup($id);
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

and **comments model**

```
function comment_add($user_id,$post_id,$post_type)
{

    $data['comment_user_id']=$user_id;
    $data['comment_post_type']=$post_type;
    $data['comment_post_id']=$post_id;
    $data['comment_text']=$this->input->post('comment_new');

    $this->db->insert('comments', $data);

    if($this->db->affected_rows()>0)
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    else
        return false;

}
```

Problem is that Comment is inserted twice and as well in database **twice**, i have been tracin this for hours even with x-Debugg found that he go through echo `$this->comments->add();`  **twice** dunno why he would do that, thanks for your help

Comment: maybe it was submited twice. Try to unbind submit when you get ajax success or just alet("something") so you will know if that problem is javascript or php based.

Comment: well yes it get submitted twice i got the alert twice ,but there's no logical reason for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that I have loaded Jquery file twice, that was my bad, thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

> maybe it was submited twice. Try to unbind submit when you get ajax
>   success or just alet("something") so you will know if that problem is
>   javascript or php based.

Replace your submit function with:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataString=$("#myform").serialize();
    $(this).unbind("submit"); //so you will submit only once

  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: base_url+"snc/category/comment_add",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data){
        $(data).hide().insertAfter('#inserAfterThis').slideDown('slow');
        $('#comment_new').val('');
        }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: it didnt work, it's php issue as i said when i ran x-debug it called comment_add() twice

Answer (score 0):

The missing piece here is "snc/category/comment_add" controller ... are you sure you aren't calling from both that controller & also the MY_Controller?

Can you post the controller code as well?

Comment: Well there's no comment_add() function in category controller, it only exists in MY_Controller

Comment: Let me rewrite this more clearly: I think your get_post_id() & get_type_id() may have a bug, and so when the initial page load is done it is passing, and then again when you click the submit.

Can you confirm they are both inserting (or not) when you click submit (same timestamps, roughly)

Comment: both inserted and exact exact datetime value hh:mm:ss